# How to check feature is enabled?

Tags: maui

Is it possible to check that feature is enabled, or is catching `FeatureNotEnabledException` or `FeatureNotSupportedException` excepprions is the only option?

For example, even if user grants permissions for accessing Location Srvices, the exception `FeatureNotEnabledException` will be thrown, if Location Services are disabled.

Comment: I think that setting a custom exception will be more flexible.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT By `setting custom exception` do you mean wrapping the standard one?

Comment: Yes, it might be cumbersome but it is reliable.

Comment: Yes, but my question is whether there's an api to avoid the exception in the first place ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I can not find such api. If I find the api like this I will inform you.